# Is pointer address swapping always an atomic operation in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

Regarding this question [Is there cases where a 32-bit variable could not been properly-aligned](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22037332/685664) and the answers provided, can I assume I can swap addresses without any side effect when working under the windows platform?

For instance:

```
struct Foo
{
    // whatever Foo can hold
};

struct Bar
{
    void buildFoo()
    {
        auto tmp = new Foo;

        // do some stuff on tmp, or not

        foo = tmp;
    }

    Foo* foo;
};
```

Now, what are the consequences of having some threads using `foo` through an instance of `Bar`, and other threads invoking `Bar::buildFoo()`?

Comment: Swapping is generally *not* atomic. It has to read two values, and write to two values. (So that when swapping `a` and `b`, `a` ends up with `b`'s old value and `b` ends up with `a`'s old value)

Comment: jalf is right that _swapping_ is generally not atomic, however Windows does provide methods such as [InterlockedExchangePointer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683609.aspx), among others, as a way to perform the swap.

Comment: Note that you do not `swap`, you're *assigning*.

Comment: Note also that pointer may be 64-bits.

Comment: @Jarod42: I am not swapping, indeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**The C++ Standard**

**No**, concurrently modifying/accessing raw<sup>2</sup> pointers are not guaranteed to be an atomic operation in c++.

The C++ standard says that a data race is present if one thread modifies a memory location and another one modifies/access the same memory location, and if such a data race is present the program suffers from *undefined behavior*.

> [**intro.multithread**]
>
> 4) Two expressions evaluations *conflict* if one of them modifies a memory location (1.7) and the other one accesses or modifies the same memory location.
>
> ...
>
> 21) The execution of a program contains a *data race* if it contains two conflicting actions in different threads, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other. Any such dat race results in undefined behavior.

<sup><sup>1.</sup> *raw* is in not being wrapped in `std::atomic<Foo*>`, or equivalent.</sup>

---

**Implementation specific behaviour (windows 32/64bit)**

Under windows it's guaranteed that read/writes to *properly-aligned* `32-bit` variables are always *atomic*, as is stated by [the article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684122%28VS.85%29.aspx) linked by the [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22037332/685664) you have referenced earlier.

Access to properly aligned `64-bit` variables are also atomic on `64-bit` windows.

> **Interlocked Variable Access** - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684122%28VS.85%29.aspx
>
> Simple reads and writes to properly-aligned 32-bit variables are atomic operations. In other words, you will not end up with only one portion of the variable updated; all bits are updated in an atomic fashion.
>
> However, access is not guaranteed to be synchronized. If two threads are reading and writing from the same variable, you cannot determine if one thread will perform its read operation before the other performs its write operation.

---

**What does this mean?**

The standard says one thing, while the documentation from microsoft says another.. which are we to trust and work with? It certainly depends on what we are doing.

If we are developing soley for the windows platform we could read up on what the used compiler guarantees in regards of code generation and go from there, but if we want to write code that might be compiled and run under different platforms the only thing to properly trust is the standard.

---

**So when working under windows I can safely *swap* 32-bit variables?**

If you by *"swapping"* mean an operation such as what is written in the snippet below the answer is **No**, but if you mean *"to assign"* the answer is **Yes**.

```
void swap (int& a, int& b) {
  int tmp = a;
  
  a = b;
  b = tmp;
}

int main () {
  int x = 1;
  int y = 2;

  swap (x, y);
}
```

Nothing in the above snippet (or the previously mentioned documentation) says that this will be an atomic operation, and when looking at the implementation of our `swap` we easily see that the operations aren't synchronized properly.

Reading/writing a single 32-bit variable is safe under windows, but in the above there's nothing that guarantees that both `x` and `y` doesn't have the value `2` when we are in the middle of our `swap`.

It is, however, guaranteed that `x` never will consist of 50% of the bytes in the previous `x` and 50% of the bytes in `y`, or similar.. the individiual writes are atomic.

Comment: Actually the ms docs say the same: while read/write may be atomic (and its actually the intel specification of the processor that should be referred to), swapping (which involves multiple of those) is certainly not.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `foo` may be atomic, but it's implementation specific. The reason for this is that most platforms write to a word sized address in a single instruction, and this is an atomic operation. However, there's no requirement that your platform store its pointers in a word sized location, although it'd be rare not to.

You also need to take into account instruction reordering and the fact that other threads may not see the write to `foo` for some time the location of the pointer may be held in the processor cache and not flushed to memory.

Given all this you're better of using the `std::atomic` types, or if you don't have access to C++11 then there should be some sort of interlocked read/write functions available.